# Polymer iron-grid doesn't work when nodes create dynamically

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

When elements created dynamically using data binding (including those in dom-repeat and dom-if templates), iron-grid component doesn't toggle responsive classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call onResize event after that elements created, like this:

```
var grid = this.$.grid;
grid.currentScreenformat = null;
grid.onResize();
```

Comment: Since, iron-grid uses the iron-resizable-behavior, you should call grid.notifyResize() instead of calling grid.onResize() directly.

Comment: the Best answer. thanks so much. However as @abhiweb said `grid.notifyResize()` does work either.